# Pip is not found after creating new python virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to create new Python virtual environment, but I have problems with pip.

I want my virtual environment to run on Python 3.10, but my default system Python version is 3.9.5. So I downloaded Python 3.10 with

```
sudo apt-get install python3.10
```

and then i run

```
python3 -m virtualenv venv --python=python3.10
```

to create virtual environment.

The problem is, when I try to use pip I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<my user name>/venv/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

I tried running

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

but got an error:

```
/home/pablo/venv/bin/python: No module named ensurepip
```

Also running `whereis pip` shows, that there are some pips in the virtual environment.

```
pip: /usr/bin/pip /home/<my user name>/venv/bin/pip3.10 /home/<my user name>/venv/bin/pip /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz
```

Also, when I create virtual environments with my default python interpreter, everything works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using pyenv with pyenv-virtualenv. In my experience it's just too much work to go manual. Sorry I know this is not a true answer, but having wasted hours and hours on similar issues, I feel like sharing )

Answer (score 1):

your installed binary executable is named as **pip3.10**(/usr/bin/pip /home//venv/bin/pip3.10). So you should use the same name to call it, just **pip** wouldn't work. Have you tried that?

Comment: Running `pip3.10 --version` produces the same error.